# Are <cmath> functions required to be `noexcept` in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, noexcept

While optimizing certain parts of my code, I decided to check if I can declare certain methods as `noexcept`, which boiled down to my incomplete knowledge about math functions from `<cmath>`.

So, I decided to check if `sin()` and `asin()` (as examples) that I am using are, in fact, `noexcept`.

```
static_assert(noexcept(asin(1)));
static_assert(noexcept(sin(1)));
```

which successfully passed, so they **are in fact `noexcept`**. I also looked inside the corresponding definition in the standard library implementation:

```
template <class _A1>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_A1>::value, double>::type
asin(_A1 __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return ::asin((double)__lcpp_x);}
```

which confirmed the `noexcept`ness of them, at least in the implementation I am currently using.

However, I was not able to find **if that is a guaranteed behavior**, say, required by the standard. So, I wonder if it is or it is not the required behavior. And if it is not, what is the motivation of not requiring them to be `noexcept`?

My [usual reference cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) does not list `noexcept` for those functions (see [this, in comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/begin)). Probably, some confusion comes here from the compatibility with C; however, I cannot find a convincing logic as `<cmath>` obviously uses C++ headers, not the C-compatibility ones.

Comment: Note that, even for features available in C, cppreference has distinct pages for C and C++. So the link you provide is exclusively for C++, the C equivalent is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sin). So, in case there was any confusion at that level, the cppreference page for `std::sin` in C++ does not have to account for C, there is a separate page for that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux good point. Which pretty much strengthens my question :)

Comment: The standard doesn't seem to require this but an implementation of course can provide stronger exception specifications. Note that a conforming `<cmath>` could simply contain code similar to `namespace std { #include <math.h> }`. Perhaps the standard doesn't bother to specify noexcept just because it wants to allow this kind of implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[res.on.exception.handling]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#res.on.exception.handling-5) states:

> An implementation may strengthen the exception specification for a non-virtual function by adding a non-throwing exception specification.

They are not *required* to be `noexcept`, but an implementation is *allowed* to mark them `noexcept`. What you are seeing is that your implementation chose to mark them as such, but cppreference doesn't mark them because they're not required to be.

> And if it is not, what is the motivation of not requiring them to be noexcept?

The usual Lakos rule applies - some of these functions have narrow contracts, so an implementation could hypothetically choose to throw out of contract, etc.